# Playa upgrade error in EE 2.9

Tags: playa

I've just upgraded to EE 2.9 and trying to update Playa to 4.5.

When I go to Fieldtypes -> Playa I get this error:

> A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1060
>
> Duplicate column name 'parent_element_id'
>
> ALTER TABLE exp_playa_relationships ADD parent_element_id VARCHAR(255)
>   NULL AFTER parent_var_id
>
> Filename: third_party/playa/ft.playa.php
>
> Line Number: 488

The previous version I had installed was 4.4.5 - I've tried setting it to 4.4.4 in exp_fieldtypes as well but same error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For some reason sometime the update is applied but EE does not change the version number. I'm not even sure on which side the error happens, but setting the version number to 4.5 in exp_fieldtypes should solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, I have this problem a lot with alls kinds of add-ons.

Comment: I had the same problems, EE2.9, i've just updated from Playa 4.4.5 to 4.5.1. Changing to 4.5.1 in the exp_fieltypes has solved the problem

Comment: Just adding that I've had this same issue going from 4.4.5 to 4.5.1. Changing the version fixed the error.

Comment: Jon, it's an issue we're aware of - we have ideas on how to fix that, but that requires time and other luxuries, so until we manage to get on top of it, this probably will come up from time to time :(

Comment: Also hit by this one today, the above solution fixed it. Ran this SQL: UPDATE `exp_fieldtypes` SET  `version` =  '4.5' WHERE `name` =  'playa'

Comment: Ditto on the problem and the fix moving to Playa 4.5.2 in 2.9.2, for what it's worth. Thanks for the fix!

Comment: Fixed it for me too, cheers Andris.