# Playa Upgrade 2.9 - playa not installed and now unable to load site preferences error

Tags: playa, error, upgrade

I upgraded a site from EE 1.7.3 to EE 2.9.1 - the last piece was upgrading Playa.  The site was working fine until that point. When I went to upgrade Playa, I received the following error:

> Error Number: 1060 Duplicate column name 'parent_element_id' ALTER
>   TABLE exp_playa_relationships ADD parent_element_id VARCHAR(255) NULL
>   AFTER parent_var_id Filename: third_party/playa/ft.playa.php Line
>   Number: 488

After checking for parent_var_id and parent_is_draft (both exist) I went to set the version number to 4.5 in exp_fieldtypes - however there is no playa field listed in that table.

Also, now the site and control panel do not load and instead I'm getting:

> Site Error: Unable to Load Site Preferences; Invalid Preference Data

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Which version of Playa do you have installed? You could try updating to the latest, just released Playa 4.5.1 version.

Comment: 4.5, which was the version available this morning. I'll try 4.5.1

Comment: I just redid the entire upgrade again, upgrading to Playa 4.4.5 first and then after that was working, I upgraded to 4.5.1

Comment: Good find, it's always recommended to update add-ons first, then EE.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution to the above issue: https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/24657/189

in short, run this SQL and run module updates again:

```
UPDATE  `exp_fieldtypes` SET  `version` =  '4.5' WHERE `name` =  'playa'
```

Comment: Sadly, I did try that and it did not work for me.