# P&T Playa update from 4.4.5 to 4.5.1 database error

Tags: playa, pixelandtonic

This has been covered elsewhere for earlier versions but the solution doesn't seem to fix this issue. I'm getting the following error when I update from Playa 4.4.5 to 4.5.1, on EE 2.7.2:

```
A Database Error Occurred
enter preformatted text here`Error Number: 1060

Duplicate column name 'parent_element_id'

ALTER TABLE exp_playa_relationships ADD parent_element_id VARCHAR(255) NULL AFTER parent_var_id

Filename: third_party/playa/ft.playa.php

Line Number: 488
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, setting the version number to 4.5 in exp_fieldtypes should solve your problem. I modified the version number inside the EE database, inside this exp_fieldtypes.

Related answers
[Playa upgrade error in EE 2.9](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/24653/playa-upgrade-error-in-ee-2-9)

Comment: This has worked for me as well. Does seem to be a somewhat common issue with Matrix & Playa lately.